# MySQL get every first 3 rows for every two other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

What I'm trying to achieve in `mysql` is the following:

I have a `table` with the following data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(a CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,b CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,factor INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(a,b,factor)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('A','X',90), -- should be included
('A','X',80), -- should be included
('A','X',70), -- should be included
('A','X',60), -- should NOT be included
('A','Y',70), -- should be included
('A','Y',60), -- should be included
('A','Y',50), -- should be included
('A','Y',40); -- should NOT be included
```

What I would like is my query to return every first three rows per combination of `column_a`and `column_b`. So that the highest 3 rows of factor will remain.

```
+---+---+--------+
| a | b | factor |
+---+---+--------+
| A | X |     90 |
| A | X |     80 |
| A | X |     70 |
| A | Y |     70 |
| A | Y |     60 |
| A | Y |     50 |
+---+---+--------+
```

I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140589/mysql-query-select-top-3-rows-from-table-for-each-category) solution but this one works with only one column instead of two.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How does the rows are ordered? How to determine that the row is 1st, 2nd,.... ? remember - posessional order is not safe.

Comment: Hi, first ordering  = `column_a ASC, column_b ASC, factor DESC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For versions of MySQL pre-8.0...

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.a = x.a 
   AND y.b = x.b 
   AND y.factor >= x.factor 
 GROUP 
    BY x.a
     , x.b
     , x.factor 
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3 
 ORDER 
    BY a
     , b
     , factor DESC;
```

...and for next time, please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY column_a, column_b 
                                         ORDER BY  factor DESC ) rn
              FROM table )
SELECT column_a, column_b, factor
FROM cte 
WHERE rn <= 3;
```